# VBA Loop function to different column and sheets

Tags: excel, vba

My problem: I have the below ‘Original Code’ which works for deleting rows with a value of ‘0’ in column Q for sheets 3 & 4 of a workbook.

I now need to incorporate the same function for sheets 6 & 7 but this time for column ‘C’. I need help to loop the function for the additional sheets and different column. I can't just copy and paste the same function again and change to column range so just not sure what I am missing to allow me to remove '0' values from column C in sheets 6 & 7.

```
Dim deleteRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For i = 3 To 4
        Sheets(i).Select

        Set ws = ActiveSheet

        For deleteRow = ws.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

            If ws.Range("Q" & deleteRow).Value = 0 Then
              Rows(deleteRow).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        Next deleteRow
    Next
End sub
```

Comment: _"I can't just copy and paste the same function again..."_, why?

Answer (score 2):

Try to create `Sub` with parameters and call it later how You want :)

```
Sub delR(startSheet As Long, endSheet As Long, setCol As String)

Dim deleteRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

        For i = startSheet To endSheet
            Sheets(i).Select

            Set ws = ActiveSheet

            For deleteRow = ws.Range(setCol & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

                If ws.Range(setCol & deleteRow).Value = 0 Then
                    Rows(deleteRow).EntireRow.Delete
                End If

            Next deleteRow
        Next

End Sub

Sub test_delR()

    Call delR(3, 4, "Q")
    Call delR(6, 7, "C")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

An addition to @Teamothy's answer: If you're about to work loop-like with distinct, non-contiguous values, you can use an `Array()` solution, like this:

```
Dim arSheets() As Variant   ' this method works with Variant only
Dim arCols() as Variant
Dim i As Long

arSheets = Array(3, 4, 6, 7)
arCols = ("Q", "Q", "C", "C")

For i = LBound(arSheets) To UBound(arSheets)
    delR_mod arSheets(i), arCols(i)
Next
```

NB1: Obviously, `delR_mod` would process only 1 sheet and accept only two parameters.

NB2: If you use only one array, you can use `For Each some_variant In arSheets` or even `For Each some_variant In Array(3, 4, 6, 7)`